how to increase lvm volume size, when another volume uses all the remaining space
I have an Oracle Linux 9 running as VM in VmWare Workstation.
The VM itself is thin provisioned and may grow to 200Gb, unfortunately, in the VM itself.
the volumes are configured as follows

/ (root) -> 70Gb
/home -> 130Gb

both are in the same LVM volumegroup, as two different block devices.
now my root partition is getting full and I need to find a way to solve this problem.
Unfortunately the filesystem is xfs, so shrinking is not possible.
At first I thought it might be possible to "just" merge the two volumes, but that doesn't seem possible.
I thought I could do the following

backup /home (only 20Gb used)
delete the /home volume
create a new smaller /home volume
restore /home
increase / (root) volume

But I have no idea if this even works, and before I start with that I wanted to check if this is even possible or if there are better ways to achieve what I want.
So, will this work or are there better/faster ways?
the data on the VM is not really important, it's just a developer machine, but I would prefer not having to install everything again.

If you have more disk space on the system where VMware workstation is running, why not just add another disk to the VM and then create another physical volume from it and add to to the volume group and then the logical volume or add space to the current disk and then run pvresize to get the space and do the same. There is plenty of information online covering how to do both.

thanks, will probably try that.
In the meantime I noticed, that docker's build artifacts used a lot of space, which I freed now. Making the problem not as urgent
